How to mock asyncio.ensure_future() and await asyncio.gather(*tasks) in pytest
lis = []
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        lis.append(
            asyncio.ensure_future(get_info(client, "example/api1", "api_1"))
        )
        lis.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_info(client, "example/api2", "api_2")))
        lis.append(
            asyncio.ensure_future(get_info(client, "example/api3", "api_3"))
        )
        infos = await asyncio.gather(*lis)
        for info in infos:
            data[info[0]] = info[1]

get_info code:-
async def get_info(client, url, key):
    resp = await client.get(url)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        res = resp.json()
    else:
        res = None
    return key, res

can anyone suggest to me how to mock the given code I'm pretty new to this Pytest?

You should not mock asyncio methods, I see you are using httpx, probably yoy need to mock httpx (wiith the help of respx library) ? Please share code for get_info

get_info code:-
async def get_info(client, url, key):
resp = await client.get(url)
if resp.status_code == 200:
res = resp.json()
else:
res = None
return key, res

@ArtiomKozyrev i have pinned get_info() code can plz look into the issue
